# What is a Virtual Getter and Setter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, getter-setter

What is the idea behind a virtual getter and setter?
Why do we need them?

I'm writing the following code while watching a tutorial:

```
login: async args => {
  const user = await User.findOne(args.email)
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("Email doesn't exist!")
  }
  const isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(args.password, user.password)
  if (!isEqual) {
    throw new Error("Wrong Password!")
  }
  jwt.sign({userId: user.id})
}
```

I'm making use of a virtual getter here to extract `user.id` but I don't really understand what's going on here.

I'm using Mongoose.

Comment: As you don't disclose user source code, nothing allows us to know whether id is virtual or not. See http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/ for some info regarding getters and setters.

Comment: It's more "idiomatic" I would say, if the developer(s) find "clearer" to use attribute-like getters instead of function calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is "going on" here, you're getting the `id` property of the `user`.

"Virtual attributes" (as commonly defined in JS, anyway) is a property that *looks* like an attribute, but may be computed (via setting, getting, or both).

You "need" them if you want to perform additional logic upon setting or getting a property, for various values of "need": you never *need* them, but you may *want* them–and sometimes they're great.

There are potential downsides to *over*-using getters/setters, like (at least AFAIK) you can't make getters or setters `async`, which may be problematic in some situations, e.g., Mongoose's `set` takes a function that'll be turned into a property setter, but you can't make it async: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2571

Answer (score 1):

Links to MDN documentation for [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

You can think of it as wrapping a property in a function where the name of the property becomes the name of the function and the value of the property is what is returned. This way you can manipulate the output before returning it.

Say your ID property is stored as a string but you need to return a number. In the getter, you may write:

```
get id() {
    return parseInt(this.id);
}
```

In the same way, using a setter, you can maybe convert the number to a string and add a prefix:

```
set id(newId) {
    this.id = "ID_" + newId.toString();
}
```